# Как расшифровать формат метода Double.ToString()

Tags: c#

В коде нашел следующую конструкцию

```
var nfi = (NumberFormatInfo)CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.NumberFormat.Clone();
nfi.NumberGroupSeparator = " ";

item.ToString("#,0.00", nfi);
```

Но нигде не могу найти как "расшифровывается" формат `"#,0.00"` (экспериментальным путем конечно установил что он форматирует число в строку с двумя знаками после запятой или двумя нулями если число целое). Но хотелось бы увидеть полный список правил расшифровки.

Comment: [справка по настраиваемым форматам](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/0c899ak8(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: @Grundy: Почему не как ответ? Ну да, ссылка, но лучше и актуальнее, чем в MSDN, всё равно не будет же.

Comment: @VladD, да я все собирался, потом думал что ссылка, потом опять собирался и в итоге забыл :-)

Comment: Спасибо, видимо не по тем ключевым словам искал

Comment: @VladD, сейчас допишу :-) готово

Answer (score 5, accepted):

В MSDN приведена [полная таблица символов применяемых в настраиваемых форматах](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/0c899ak8(v=vs.110).aspx)

Конкретно в данном случае используются

- "," - разделитель групп и описатель масштабирования чисел - используется и в качестве *разделителя групп*, и в качестве *описателя масштабирования чисел(number scalling)*.

  - **Разделитель групп**: если между двумя заполнителями для цифр ("0" или "#"), задающими форматирование целой части числа, стоит одна или несколько запятых, то между всеми группами целой части числа вставляется символ-разделитель групп.

    Пример:

    ```
    Описатель разделителя групп:
    2147483647 ("##,#", en-US) -> 2,147,483,647
    2147483647 ("##,#", es-ES) -> 2.147.483.647
    ```
  - **Описатель масштабирования чисел**: если сразу слева от явно или неявно заданного разделителя целой и дробной части стоит одна или несколько запятых, форматируемое число делится на 1000 для каждой указанной запятой. Например, если строка "0,," используется для форматирования числа 100 миллионов, то результатом является "100".

    Пример:

    ```
    Описатель масштабирования:
    2147483647 ("#,#,,", en-US) -> 2,147
    2147483647 ("#,#,,", es-ES) -> 2.147
    ```
- "#" - Заместитель цифры - Заменяет знак "#" соответствующей цифрой, если такая имеется. В противном случае в результирующей строке не будет цифры.
- "0" - Знак-заместитель нуля - Заменяет ноль соответствующей цифрой, если такая имеется. В противном случае в результирующей строке будет стоять ноль.
- "." - Разделитель - Определяет расположение разделителя целой и дробной частей в результирующей строке.

Comment: _делит число на 1000 при каждом употреблении_ — нипанятна...

Comment: @VladD, ага, там по примеру понятно, а как это по-русски записать, что то не могу придумать :-) он ведь действительно выводит уже масштабированную часть

Comment: @VladD, не не, ты пример посмотри, он выводит именно как _n / 1000_

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/44041/discussion-between-grundy-and-vladd).