# StringFormat & число только с целой частью

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

Есть ли формат для чисел с целой частью, чтобы разбивал сам по тысячам и т.д., например как N2 - 1000.01 -> 1,000.01
Но только для чисел без дробной части: 10000 -> 10.000
В интернете не нашел, либо плохо искал

Comment: `string.Format("{0:0,0}"` например. Хотя вообще нет разницы какое число передается, с дробной частью или без

Comment: Пробовал такой вариант, он если передаешь число < 10, то получишь такое: "01", "02",...,"09"

Comment: Тогда можешь использовать тот же `N`, только c `0`: `10000.ToString("N0")`

Comment: Тьфу, точно, спасибо большое, про него почему-то не подумал, попробовал N и N2, но N0 - нет

Comment: Так я про N1 и не говорил :-D я `N0` указывал

Comment: Исправил уже, ошибся кнопкой)

Comment: Связанный вопрос: [Как расшифровать формат метода Double.ToString()](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/555816/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d1%80%d0%b0%d1%81%d1%88%d0%b8%d1%84%d1%80%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%8c-%d1%84%d0%be%d1%80%d0%bc%d0%b0%d1%82-%d0%bc%d0%b5%d1%82%d0%be%d0%b4%d0%b0-double-tostring)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Для форматирования с разделителем групп можно использовать [описатель числового формата "N"](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/standard/base-types/standard-numeric-format-strings#the-numeric-n-format-specifier)

Требуемое число знаков дробной части задается спецификатором точности.

В данном случае - 0

Следовательно, для решения вопроса необходимо использовать спецификатор `N0`

```
var s = 10000.ToString("N0");
```

---

Кроме этого можно воспользоваться [`Custom numeric format`](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/standard/base-types/custom-numeric-format-strings) - а именно [описателем `,`](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/standard/base-types/custom-numeric-format-strings#the--custom-specifier-2)

В итоге формат будет выглядеть:

```
var s = string.Format("{0:#,0}", 1000);
```

Answer (score -2):

**Форматирование целых чисел**

*Для форматирования целочисленных значение применяется описатель "d":*

```
int number = 23;
string result = String.Format("{0:d}", number);
Console.WriteLine(result); // 23

string result2 = String.Format("{0:d4}", number);
Console.WriteLine(result2); // 0023

Число после описателя указывает, сколько цифр будет в числовом значении. Если в исходном числе цифр меньше, то к нему добавляются нули.*
```

*Вот и все, вместо `number`, подставляеш свою переменную с числом, и ловишь ответ.*

Comment: специально сделал 2 акцента, что число НЕ ДРОБНОЕ)

Comment: пример числа напиши сюда

Comment: Далеко ходить не надо, бери 10000 и все

Comment: Форматирование целых чисел
Для форматирования целочисленных значение применяется описатель "d":
int number = 23;
string result = String.Format("{0:d}", number);
Console.WriteLine(result); // 23
string result2 = String.Format("{0:d4}", number);
Console.WriteLine(result2); // 0023
Число после описателя указывает, сколько цифр будет в числовом значении. Если в исходном числе цифр меньше, то к нему добавляются нули.

Comment: посмотри ответ.

Comment: уже ответили выше, спасибо

Comment: тогда поставьте галочку ответ и закройте этот вопрос.

Comment: Ваш ответ не подходит, подошел ответ под вопросом от Grundy

Comment: вот так и помогай тут :(

Comment: @alexeyboltynov, но ведь ты же неправильно ответил

Comment: а ты проверь для начала, lol

Comment: @alexeyboltynov, чего проверять? :-) что у тебя даже в ответе результат который ты описываешь не совпадает с тем, что в вопросе указан? :-)

Comment: В вопросе спрашивалось как к целом числе добавить разделители для групп. У тебя в ответе - как добавить 0 до минимальной длинны